# what is the best way to convert a vector<int32_t> to int[]

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector that hold int32_t and I am working on windows 64 bit. I need to convert it to an int array.

since on my specific platform int32_t and int are essentially the same type, i can do this: (assuming that array has enough space to hold all data from vector)

```
 int out[1000]; //assuming that in has less data than 1000 
 std::vector<int32_t> in=getdata();
 memcpy(out,&int[0],in.size());
```

But it works on platform that uint32_t and int are essentially the same type.

What is the best way to do this to make sure that it is platform independent and will work on any platform that for example int is not 32 bit?

Comment: an `unsigned int` can hold values that an `int` can't so you might not be getting the same values.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about that *essentially the same type*, since even if `uint32_t` is `unsigned int`, `int` is stilled signed, so for anything beyond `INT_MAX` the bets are off.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect your comments.

Comment: as long as you create array of same types as vector - this code will be portable. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data (underlaying storage has to be array)

Comment: Can't you just use `in.data()` if `sizeof (int) == sizeof (int32_t)` holds?

Comment: int* p = &vect[0]; should work too, if you don't want to make a copy.

Comment: @ShyamalDesai that will only work if the vector never reallocates its memory.  Once it does all pointers and iterators to the contents of the vector will be invalidated.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Makes sense. sending that int* outside that function would be dangerous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for a portable way to copy the data then I would use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

```
std::copy(in.begin(), in.end(), std::begin(out));
```

If you want to go the other way around and copy an array into a vector then you can use the vector constructor that takes two iterators:

```
some_type array_name[some_size];
std::vector<some_type> vector_name(std::begin(array_name), std::end(array_name));
```

If you wanted to add the array to an already existing vector then you could use [`std::vector::assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) which will replace the contents of the vector with the array

```
some_type array_name[some_size];
vector_name.assign(std::begin(array_name), std::end(array_name));
```

If you want to keep the contents of the vector and append the contents of the array into the vector then you can use copy with a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

```
some_type array_name[some_size];
std::copy(std::begin(array_name), std::end(array_name), std::back_inserter(vector_name));
```

Comment: You can also simply use `std::copy(in.begin(), in.end(), out);`, since `copy` takes an iterator and pointers are valid iterators.

Comment: @JoshKelley But this way, the type of `out` becomes interchangeable, i.e. you can switch to `std::array out` without further changes.

Comment: @dhke: how can I use this code to copy from array to vector?

Comment: @dhke: Thanks, what about if you want to add to the vector after it was created.

Comment: @NathanOliver: At the moment, I don'y have such requirement, just want to learn, so lets look at both cases.

Comment: @mans added to the answer.  here is a really good reference site for C++: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::vector<int32_t> in=getdata();     
 std::vector<int> out( in.begin(), in.end() );
```

Then you can access `out` as an array with `out.data()`.